# DTLS: Client re-transmission timeout/ Server message waiting timeout

Tags: c, openssl, dtls

For DTLS connection setup,i require help for getting callBacks for the following conditions.

1). when Client sends ClientHello message and after some configured time at application if ServerHello does not come timeout should be received.

2). The same thing i require at server end if Server does not receive any ClientHello from client then after some configured time, timeout should be received.

My question is DOES OPENSSL provide such functionality if yes please let me know it otherwise please tell me how can i achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question (1), you could set receive timeout

```
BIO_ctrl(SSL_get_rbio(ssl), BIO_CTRL_DGRAM_SET_RECV_TIMEOUT, 0, &timeout);
```

Then in your SSL_read error handling check for BIO_CTRL_DGRAM_GET_RECV_TIMER_EXP and you could retry. There is a very good example code and explanation in http://sctp.fh-muenster.de/

Similarly on the server side. See the following example for writing a simple DTLS server/client http://sctp.fh-muenster.de/dtls/dtls_udp_echo.c.

If I were you I would start with the DTLS.pdf documentation in the above link. Hope this helps.

Comment: Archived: https://web.archive.org/web/20150627150010/http://sctp.fh-muenster.de/